# Where are all the Quick Change stations on Pandora?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm not a fan of having to run back to Sanctuary or Liar's Berg to constantly change my skills over and over.  Are there any other Quick Change stations kicking around that I can hit, to save some time?

Comment: is there a point to this question?  both this one and [the other one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95505/how-many-vending-machines-are-in-pandora) doesn't seem to fit the category of `practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. `

Comment: Indeed. What problem is this going to solve for you?

Comment: Finding a place to change stats, besides Sanctuary and Liar's Berg.

Comment: I don't want to repeatedly run back to Sanctuary, then go back to wherever my quest is JUST to change stats.

Comment: Hey, @Retrosaur, I've rejiggered your question to hopefully make it more clear.  As a note, adding in some context tends to help, as just going, "How many of X are there?" makes it sound more like idle curiosity than anything you might be having a problem with.

Comment: Outside of the DLC campaigns there aren't any besides those two.

Comment: that makes more sense, withdrawing my down vote and upvoting instead

Comment: Aren't they called New-U?

Comment: nope, new-u are the stations that you can respawn at when you die.  The ones that lets you respec and change appearance are called quick change stations.  They were called New-Us in BL1 though

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Know if there are any Quick Change stations in the DLC areas?

Comment: For the pirate DLC there's a quick change in Oasis, Hayter's Folly and The Washbourne Refinery. For the Torgue DLC There's one in Moxxi's bar, and either the main Torgue arena, the first boss's bar or both.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Add that as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main Campaign:

- Liar's Berg
- Sanctuary

Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty:

- Oasis
- Hayter's Folly
- The Washbourne Refinery

Mr Torgue and the Campaign of Carnage:

- Moxxi's Bar
- Pyro Pete's Bar

Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt:

- Hunter's Grotto
- Candlerakks' Crag

Note that there is a Quick-Change station located just before any DLC's 'invincible' boss.

Comment: @galacticninja This should answer it for you.

Answer (score 3):

**There are only two, one in Sanctuary and one in Liar's Berg.**

[Source:](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/New-U_Station)

> In Borderlands 2, the character customization options have been moved to the Quick Change station in Sanctuary and Liar's Berg.

Comment: Do you know if there are any Quick Change stations in the DLC areas?

Comment: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_Change#Locations - At least three in Pirates DLC. No mention of Torgue DLC, and I haven't played it myself yet.